# Pattern/Design approach to retrieve a specific object from various unknown sources

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm looking for a efficient way of retrieving an object for a specific class from a variable number of classes with a common parent.

in simple terms 
looking for Object of ClassA

Class B C and D all have method of different names to get said object. 
Sometimes I may need to access other objects within them to find my desired object.

I was just making a singleton class called

ObjectRetriever with one method called getObjectFromSource(Object source)

The method is currently just a series of if source instanceof ClassC to
do specific behaviour.

I'm limited to how much source I can share but was hoping there is an existing pattern/design approach for this.

Comment: [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)

Comment: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithVisitor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you do not have control over classes A-D, I believe you would want to use the Facade pattern, as that way you can slowly expand your collection of methods used to streamline access to this API.
2. If you do have control over classes A-D, you'd be better off readjusting your class hierarchy, potentially by adding an interface that includes a getA method.

> Quote from Wikipedia's Facade Pattern reference:
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern
>
> The facade pattern (or façade pattern) is a software design pattern
>   commonly used with object-oriented programming. The name is by analogy
>   to an architectural facade.
>
> A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger
>   body of code, such as a class library. A facade can:
>
> make a software library easier to use, understand and test, since the
>   facade has convenient methods for common tasks; make the library more
>   readable, for the same reason; reduce dependencies of outside code on
>   the inner workings of a library, since most code uses the facade, thus
>   allowing more flexibility in developing the system; wrap a poorly
>   designed collection of APIs with a single well-designed API (as per
>   task needs). The Facade design pattern is often used when a system is
>   very complex or difficult to understand because the system has a large
>   number of interdependent classes or its source code is unavailable.
>   This pattern hides the complexities of the larger system and provides
>   a simpler interface to the client. It typically involves a single
>   wrapper class which contains a set of members required by client.
>   These members access the system on behalf of the facade client and
>   hide the implementation details.

Comment: Should be able to use this to improve on my apporach. Ideally i would like to do 2. but the code is quite locked down. Hence needing to approach things as i am

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the clases C, B and D, you shoud create an interface that has the method to retrieve the object in question.

Like this:

```
public interface SomeNeatName{ A getA();}


public class B implements SomeNeatName {
    getA(){
        return nameOfVariableHoldingA;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i cant modify these classes, but this would work if i could